# How can I clear a "innerHTML" with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML:

```
<div id = "options"></div>
```

I access to this div trough this Javascript:

```
var test = "hola"; 
document.getElementById('options').innerHTML= 
<p>Test</p> <li>${test}</li>
```

And I have this button:

```
function click({
  document.getElementById("Click").addEventListener("click", function(){
  });
};
click();
```

I need that when that function called "click" is executed automatically that `<li>` can clean that value of the variable: "test" and it is seen empty.

How can I do it? Thank you

Comment: why is the LI not in a UL?

Comment: How is the `click()` called automatically? Please extend your code with an example.

Comment: you are passing `document...` as object to function or what should I call that ?

Comment: I don't think you want to add the `event listener` inside the `click function`, or else everytime the person clicks the element you will add another `event listener`, I would suggest looking at `DOMCONTENTLOADED` and add the `event listener` inside of that. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`el.innerHTML` is the property which keeps track of HTML text values shown inside the element. You can set that to empty whenever you want to clear it.

Try this sample - https://jsitor.com/J0gXikZmV

`<div id = "options"></div>`

```
var test = "hola"; 
let el = document.getElementById("options");

el.innerHTML = "<p>Test</p> <li>${test}</li>";

el.addEventListener('click', () => {
  el.innerHTML = '';
})
```

Here it clear the html content of `div`